# How to download only one changeset with Git?

Tags: git, bash, deployment

I didn't know how to formulate the question, I know a changeset is a set of changes.

I'm writing a deployment script in bash, so what I need is to download the minimum amount of code. I don't need to download an entire repository, I just need the code for a particular tag or hash, but not only the changes, I want the full code.

What would be the best way for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this with 'git archive' like @knittl proposed, and worked fine

```
$ git archive v2.0.0 --remote=git@bitbucket.org:john/myapp.git --output=myapp.zip --format=zip
```

It threw an error when trying to unzip when I didn't add '--format=zip', it didn't guess it correctly from the filename like the man page said.

Comment: git archive is the best way for this indeed.

Comment: By default, the format is .tar, so you can use `tar xvf` to extract it (if you are using linux)